# how to enable pause and resume in audio recorder in windows phone 8?(Details Insde)

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8

I'm working on the audio recorder in windows phone 8. I've done audio recording start and stop functionality but I don't find any pause and resume audio recording feature. Also don't know how to add details to the recorded audio like created DateTime, album art etc.,

I've seen the Microphone Class but I can't find anything.

I've seen Microphone.GetData method and trying to use it, please say me, if somebody knows about this or knows any helpful links. . .

Comment: There is MediaPlayer.Stop and MediaPlayer.Play. Try that. I am not sure on windows phone but it works on desktop applications.

Comment: On windows phone, there is Microphone.Start() and Microphone.Stop(), but me don't know how to pause and resume. . .

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started
```

Comment: Are you sure that's `==`?

Comment: If it's inside If statement then yes.