# Pause and Resume in Microphone: Windows phone 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am beginner in Windows phone. I created the recorder example and also executed successfully in windows phone 7. But I have to add the pause and resume functionality in my application.

Note: I used microphone for the recording.

How can I put push and resume functionality in microphone for recording?

OR give me any alternative solution for recording in windows phone.

here is my code..

```
Microphone mphone;
List<byte[]> memobuffercollection = new List<byte[]>();
DynamicSoundEffectInstance playback;

private void BtnRecords_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Clear the collection for storing the buffers
   memobuffercollection.Clear();

   // Stop any playback in Progress
   playback.Stop();

   // Start Recording
   mphone.Start();        
   BtnStop.Opacity = 1;
   BtnRecords.Opacity = 0;        
}    

private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StopRecording();
    BtnStop.Opacity = 0;
    BtnRecords.Opacity = 1;
}

void StopRecording()
{
    // Get the last partial buffer
    int sampleSize = mphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(mphone.BufferDuration);
    byte[] extraBuffer = new byte[sampleSize];
    int extraBytes = mphone.GetData(extraBuffer);

    // Stop Recording
    mphone.Stop();                  

    // Create MemoInfo object and add at top of collection
    int totalSize = memobuffercollection.Count * sampleSize + extraBytes;
    TimeSpan duration = mphone.GetSampleDuration(totalSize);
    MemoInfo memoInfo = new MemoInfo(DateTime.UtcNow, totalSize, duration);
    memofiles.Insert(0, memoInfo);

    // Save Data in IsolatedStorage 
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile(memoInfo.FileName))
        {
            // Write buffers from collection
            foreach (byte[] buffer in memobuffercollection)
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Write partial buffer
            stream.Write(extraBuffer, 0, extraBytes);
        }
    }

    memosListBox.UpdateLayout();
    memosListBox.ScrollIntoView(memoInfo);


}
```

And memoinfo is my class which is used for giving the title to recorded audio.

Comment: show us your codes please.

Comment: ok..
i will edit it..
thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone_methods.aspx) of `Microphone`, you will find out that there is no `Pause()` or `Resume()` method in `Microphone` class. Only playback has Pause & Resume features ( read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598930.aspx) ).

The only way to pause & resume, is to stop recording, save the audio file, and record a new one when you "resume". Last, combine the audio files together to one.

Related Question (though it's for Windows Phone 8): [how to enable pause and resume in audio recorder in windows phone 8?(Details Insde)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597520/how-to-enable-pause-and-resume-in-audio-recorder-in-windows-phone-8details-ins)

Comment: ok.
finally, i have to use the only way like stop recording and save that audio and combine it with old recorded audio.
Thank You